# How to suppress these warnings

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging

after some google, i find this code, but it does not work.

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

The following still display the warning messages as below

```
2021-05-27 22:04:57.755845: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-05-27 22:04:57.756056: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.


2021-05-27 22:05:39.988042: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2021-05-27 22:05:39.988241: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2021-05-27 22:05:39.996417: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: (machine name)
2021-05-27 22:05:39.996655: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: (username)
2021-05-27 22:05:39.997423: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

2021-05-27 22:05:40.926604: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: People will need more context about the warnings you are trying to suppress. Please, add a bit of context about your code.

Answer (score 0):

The following workaround will stop showing the Tensorflow warnings

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```